# Issue when deploying project with Munits in Azure Devops

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, munit

Caused by: org.mule.maven.client.api.BundleDependenciesResolutionException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.1 in maven-central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)

thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Paramesh! Nice to see you contributing to stack overflow, please remember to provide better information and full documentation:
- Write a little summarize of what are you trying or doing
- Introduce the problem first, before you show us the error 
- Posting the error may not be enough, so post any other relevan information

Answer (score 0):

It may help others also to give an answer eventhough it is little bit late.
We had this issue where the embedded runtime container or    is not being downloaded from anypoint studio. We have looked at the maven repo and we could not find the  version 4.2.1
what we found was 4.1.1  from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/distributions/mule-module-embedded-impl-bom/
And the latest is found under the mulesoft repo
The solution is to add mulesoft repo and try it from maven command line

mvn clean package

This will bring your dependecy to your local repo and after that you can run munit it from anypoint studio